# SQL Query Issue - msg 213

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some issues getting a query that worked just fine in SQL Server 2008 R2 and after upgrading to 2014 it no longer does. Any help would be appreciated. The error i'm getting is:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 1 
> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

> DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Here is the Query:

```
use AccessControl 
set nocount on

declare @MaintResults table
(
Result int identity(1,1),
Cardholder_Count varchar(15),
Events_Count  varchar(15),
User_Count varchar(15),
```

etc...

```
)
```

The query all together is about 10 pages long. Its purpose is to pull a decent amount of information out of a database, into a temporary table and where it can be viewed. I'm honestly not sure why i'm getting this issue because the name of the database is in fact "AccessControl".. so why am i getting the error I am?

Comment: The message suggests that somewhere you have something like `INSERT INTO X (Col1) VALUES (1, 2)` or vice versa.  i.e. more columns than values or more values than columns.

Comment: Try splitting the query up to pinpoint the location.

Answer (score 0):

For us to solve this for you, we will need to see the entire statement.

As plain as the error states, either you are selecting a different number of columns when you insert into the table variable

- But you stated nothing has changed except an upgrade to SQL server

Otherwise, one of the types in the select statement is no longer compatible with the table variable. This could be as simple as one or two of the fields are the wrong way around, from your select and your insert statements.

I'm not going to analyse too deeply what caused this without a lot more information from OP but if you have upgraded your DB and your application is maintaining the Schema it could be that some minor schema changes were also introduced, either that or some implicit type conversion that worked in the previous version is no longer supported?

> Run the Select to fill the table variable on its own, manually review that types are ok and that they match your table variable.
>
> You can cheat by saving the select as a view and then compare the column definitions of the view to your table variable